# How can I Login to website using Suitescript 2.0?

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Literally, I do not know what module is to get values from http, https.
I'm trying to bring tracking numbers from kind of BANC, UPS, FedEx...
My purpose is this reference specific values from other site and bring back to Netsuite.

## 1 What modules do I use for that?

## 2 If there is a login session, is it possible to access using suitescript?

your answer will be great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing that information is usually done via API with credentials rather than a login session. For that you normally use N/https.